# android adb frequently disconnects from eclipse?

Tags: android, android-emulator

My android adb automatically disconnects from eclipse,every time i need to reset adb from ddms manager setting it is very hectic during project development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this restart the adb server. or, kill the adb server and restart the eclipse.

c:>adb kill-server
Restarting the eclipse will start the adb server.